How can I optimize performance when querying large time series datasets in GridDB?
I'm using GridDB to store and query large time series datasets, and I've noticed that query performance decreases significantly as the dataset grows. Specifically, queries that involve large date ranges or complex filtering conditions are taking longer to execute than expected.
I’ve already indexed the timestamp column, but the performance issue persists. Are there any best practices or specific configurations in GridDB that can help optimize query performance for large time series datasets?

After a detailed research I came to find that dealing with large datasets in GridDB, query optimisation can be done by several strategies

Time based splitting of data into multiple containers. This way it targets only relevant partition.
In addition to timestamp column indexing, add secondary indexes on other columns lying in filtering conditions. Thus reducing amount of data scanned.

There could be more other ways for sure
